# Echo multiple lines into file exactly as it is presented

Tags: bash, debian

So, I have an installer script that, at one point, writes multiple lines to a file. It's another script. I want it to echo:

```
cat > $BASEDIR/start.sh << EndOfMessage
 cd $BASEDIR/
 VER=$(ls | grep --exclude-dir="Spigot" "spigot" | sort -nr)
 java -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -jar "$VER" -o true 
 sleep 5
 echo "Restarting..." && bash $BASEDIR/start.sh
EndOfMessage
```

However, it replaces "$VAR" with blank space, and some other lines are omitted. Is there a way to echo that all EXACTLY as it is presented there? I prefer it to be all in the same script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either escape all of the dollar signs in the here-document, or just quote the end-of-document string (which turns off all expansions within the document):

```
cat > $BASEDIR/start.sh << 'EndOfMessage'  # Quotes prevent expansions in the here-doc
 cd $BASEDIR/
 VER=$(ls | grep --exclude-dir="Spigot" "spigot" | sort -nr)
 java -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -jar "$VER" -o true 
 sleep 5
 echo "Restarting..." && bash $BASEDIR/start.sh
EndOfMessage
```